# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION upon pressing a button

Tags: ios, swift, exc-bad-instruction

I'm newbie in Swift and I'm currenlty trying to learn it but I faced a mystery issue. As you can see in the image below, there are some controls that are linked properly to this View Controller and upon pressing a button in the UI we execute this code below but I always got an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. I don't understand why!!

[image]

Here is some info from the stack trace.

```
(lldb) thread info
thread #1: tid = 0x9319, 0x0006c5d5 App`App.AViewController.sendCommentViaEmail (self=<unavailable>)() -> () + 9349 at AViewController.swift:49, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

(lldb) frame select 1
frame #1: 0x037067cd libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84:
-> 0x37067cd:  addl   $0x1c, %esp
   0x37067d0:  popl   %esi
   0x37067d1:  popl   %edi
   0x37067d2:  popl   %ebx
```

EDITED:

Stacktrace below

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x1e19, 0x0005a5d5 A`A.AViewController.sendCommentViaEmail (self=<unavailable>)() -> () + 9349 at AViewController.swift:49, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x0005a5d5 A`A.AViewController.sendCommentViaEmail (self=<unavailable>)() -> () + 9349 at AViewController.swift:49
    frame #1: 0x036f47cd libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    frame #2: 0x01ea323d UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    frame #3: 0x02213840 UIKit`-[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    frame #4: 0x036f47cd libobjc.A.dylib`-[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 84
    frame #5: 0x01ea323d UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 99
    frame #6: 0x01ea31cf UIKit`-[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 64
    frame #7: 0x01fd6e86 UIKit`-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 69
    frame #8: 0x01fd72a3 UIKit`-[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 598
    frame #9: 0x01fd650d UIKit`-[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 660
    frame #10: 0x01ef360a UIKit`-[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 874
    frame #11: 0x01ef40e5 UIKit`-[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 791
    frame #12: 0x01eb9549 UIKit`-[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    frame #13: 0x01ec937e UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 20690
    frame #14: 0x01e9db19 UIKit`_UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2206
    frame #15: 0x039791df CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    frame #16: 0x0396eced CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    frame #17: 0x0396e248 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 952
    frame #18: 0x0396dbcb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    frame #19: 0x0396d9fb CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    frame #20: 0x085dc24f GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 192
    frame #21: 0x085dc08c GraphicsServices`GSEventRun + 104
    frame #22: 0x01ea18b6 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1526
    frame #23: 0x000919cc A`main(argc=1, argv=0xbffaa62c) + 76 at main.m:12
    frame #24: 0x04490ac9 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Here are the properties I'm using:
I got the same result whether they are linked to the UI or not.

[image: Properties linked to the UI controls and same result]

Comment: Show the stack trace from Xcode.

Comment: How do you instantiate the view controller that this code is in?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the Connection Inspector for the switch?

Comment: Do you have an old connection from your storyboard to your @IBOutlet var?

Answer (score 2):

Where does `emailToMyselfSwitch` come from? If it's an **IBOutlet** it seems that you forgot to connect it from IB to your code. If that's not the case please show more context.

Comment: Nope, it's already connected and even it's not, it should not crash!! At least this what I know..

Comment: It will crash. Because you are defining the property as an unwrapped optional but without the connection from Interface Builder, the property will be nil: therefore trying to access your unwrapped (nil) optional will try to dereference a null pointer

Comment: Make sure the control is linked to your IBOutlet by right clicking the switch control on your interface builder

Comment: It still seems to me that the switch control is not connected to your outlet. Maybe the *action* is connected to the IBAction but not the IBOutlet and you need to connect both.

Answer (score 1):

This error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` generally means that you are calling a property or method (selector?) on a null object or an object that can't respond to the selector ie `self.null.on` or a property that cannot be accessed because it was released.

I've had trouble in the past with these weak vars falling away. Try deleting the `weak` in your property.

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct. The problem is not in the connection with outlet. I´ve tested and prints: "Value: nil"
The problem is in other part of code. 
The message "self=" is not normal.
You can show us more information.

[image]